# How do I use the value of an XML element when setting the path in the Java SimpleXML library?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<rdr>
  <details>
    <detail>
        <name>version</name>
        <value>15.0</value>
    </detail>
    <detail>
        <name>resolution</name>
        <value>1080X1920</value>
    </detail>
  </details>
</rdr>
```

and I am marshalling this into the following Java bean:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Path;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "rdr", strict = false)
public class XmlBean {

@Path("details/detail[1]")
@Element(name = "value")
private String version;

@Path("details/detail[2]")
@Element(name = "value")
private String resolution;

public String getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public String getResolution() {
    return resolution;
}

public void setResolution(String resolution) {
    this.resolution = resolution;
}

}
```

I am using simple XML, version 2.6.6 to achieve this:  http://simple.sourceforge.net/

However, what I would like to do, is use the name elements in the XPath.  For example, rather than using the Path "details/detail[1]" I would like to use "details/detail[name=version]".  This doesn't work and I get an org.simpleframework.xml.core.PathException: Invalid index for path exception returned.  I have tried surrounding version with ' to no avail.  From what I understand of XPath, this is the correct syntax:  http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp  Can anyone confirm that this looks correct?

I've looked into the source code for the simple xml library and it is handling the XPath processing by itself without using a 3rd party library.  I can see why it doesn't work, because it is only accepting digits and will throw that exception for any char that isn't a digit.

I'm tempted to fix the library, but suspect that I am doing something wrong and that there may be another annotation that I should be using or some other syntax.

Is there another annotation that I can use to achieve what I am trying to do?  Is it possible to do what I am trying to do using Simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I resolved this by writing my own library available from here: https://github.com/aembleton/XML-Marshaller

It's pretty simple and basic but solved the problem at the time.

Answer (score 0):

this is how it would look in xpath: /rdr/details/detail[name='version']/value/text()

so maybe try:

```
@Path("details/detail[name='version']")
@Element(name = "value")
private String resolution;
```

see the ''
it needs to know this is text

Comment: I have tried that, and I get the same error.  Like I mentioned, I know why this is from looking through the source.  SimpleXML is looking for and only accepting a digit.  Anything else results in a PathException being thrown.

I would like to know if there is a different syntax that is used by SimpleXML or if there is another annotation that I can use.

Comment: did u try stuff like: name="version" or with escape characters like: name=\'version\' or name=\"version\"

Comment: look at this: public OrderManager(@ElementList(name="orders") List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }  its from here: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php so maybe double quot will work

Comment: Yael, I've tried using " and escaping it.  I've looked at the source so I know it can't process non-digits anyway.  I have seen the ElementList and that is an option along with using numbers [1], [2] etc.  I just hoped there'd be a better way.

Comment: which jar are u using exactly ? and which version ?

Answer (score 0):

Using SimpleXML ver: 2.6.6. - without using the annotation `@Element(name = "value")` you can do the following:

```
/**
 * User: alfasin
 * Date: 8/21/13
 */

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Path;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;

import java.io.File;

@Root(name = "rdr", strict = false)
public class SimpleXml {
    @Element
    @Path("details/detail[1]")
    private String name;

    @Element
    @Path("details/detail[1]")
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Nir\\IdeaProjects\\Play\\rdr.xml";
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        File source = new File(fileName);

        SimpleXml example = serializer.read(SimpleXml.class, source);
        System.out.println(example.getName());
        System.out.println(example.getValue());
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
version
15.0
```

However, according to [*the documentation*](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Path.html), using XPATH requires that you'll name the variable with the same name that is used in the XML, alas, you can't have two class members sharing the same name ("name and "value"), which means that you cannot use XPATH unless you have only ONE `detail` object in the XML.